# How to handle exceptions with Swagger?

Tags: jersey, jax-rs, swagger

I am building some test APIs using swagger (1.5) and JAX-rs with Jersey (1.13) and I m trying to implement exception handling. For example I have the following code when receiving the results from my DB (Elasticsearch)

```
@POST
@Path("/category")
@ApiOperation(value="returns products")
@Produces({ "application/json" })
public Response getPostCategories( 
        @ApiParam(value="keyphrase, required=true) @QueryParam("keyphrase") String keyphrase,
        @ApiParam(value="category) @QueryParam("category") String category,     
        @Context SecurityContext securityContext) 
throws WebApplicationException {        
    SearchRequest searchRequest = new SearchRequest();
    searchRequest.setKeyphrase(keyphrase);
    searchRequest.setCategory(category);

    SearchCategoryQuery categoryQuery = new SearchCategoryQuery();
    String searchResponse = null;
    try
    {           
        searchResponse = categoryQuery.searchCategory(searchRequest);
    }
    catch (WebApplicationException ex)
    {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity("results no found").type(javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).build());
    }
    return Response.ok(searchResponse).build();
}
```

However, in the output swagger always prints the same response[image]

What I need instead is to receive the error messages I specify in each exception. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Swagger by itself does not handle application exceptions as yet.

You will either need to create custom Exception classes (that extend `java.lang.exception`) or use the existing ones (like `WebApplicationException` that you are already using) and make the API definition throw these errors. So basically you need to use Java/J2EE/Jersey to throw proper exceptions. Swagger UI will display them for you.

Check [this](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring) link for details on REST exception handling with Spring.

Comment: Hi , still I m not able to print a custom error message. Swagger keeps printing: "no content" and "error no response from the server" I updated my code above. Maybe you could have a look

Comment: have you created an exceptionmapper as described in the suggested link?

Comment: No really. If I get it right there are two options. One is to throw the WebApplicationException and the other is to map the custom exceptions to the ExceptionMapper. I decided to go for the first one. Shouldnt it print the message specified in the thrown exception? ("results no found")

Comment: modified link in the answer; please check now.

Comment: broken link @Sampada :/

Comment: @MiguelRuiz - added a new one.